# Unity3d Unable to generate Uri link to start dwonload assetbundle

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore

Greeting,

Recently, I been experimenting Unity3d and Firebase for some projects. I managed to download images from Firebase Storage and tried to do the same for assetbundle.

But when I start download, it just stop at `Debug.Log("download link generated");`
Usually it will give me the Uri link after that. 
I tested the code again at my image download scene, it still work.

Did anyone experience this before? Or I missing out something that need to prepare for assetbundle download?

Forgot to mention, it's still in the same project. But different scene.

```
public void DownloadStarted()
    {
        StorageReference asset_ref = storage.GetReferenceFromUrl("gs://dummy_link.appspot.com/test_folder/Test_Asset/testbox");

        asset_ref.GetDownloadUrlAsync().ContinueWith((Task<Uri> task) =>
        {
            if (task.IsFaulted && task.IsCanceled)
            {
                Debug.Log(task.Exception.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("download link generated");
                Debug.Log("Download URL: " + task.Result);
                downloadLink = task.Result;
                _isDownload = true;

                StartCoroutine(DownloadAsset(task.Result));
            }
        });
    }

    IEnumerator DownloadAsset(Uri uri)
    {
        Debug.Log("Start Download");

        using (UnityWebRequest uwr = UnityWebRequestAssetBundle.GetAssetBundle(uri))
        {
            yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();

            if (uwr.isNetworkError || uwr.isHttpError)
            {
                Debug.Log(uwr.error);
            }
            else
            {

                AssetBundle bundle = DownloadHandlerAssetBundle.GetContent(uwr);

                GameObject instance = Instantiate(bundle.LoadAsset("cube", typeof(GameObject)), gameObj.transform) as GameObject;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: btw i think it should rather be `if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled)` .. instead of `&&`

Comment: I am a total outsider to Unity3D api. But please check if the `Result` property should be available at the Download start phase, or only at the end.

It might be the case that sometimes it downloads the asset super fast (then you get the second Log), and cases that it hasn't finished yet and it just halts.

Answer (score 1):

[`ContinueWith`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith) might be executed on a thread different to the Unity main thread.

Most of Unity's API only works in the main thread.

In your case `StartCoroutine` will probably silently(?) fail in a thread.

---

specifically for Unity there is an extension in Firebase  [`ContinueWithOnMainThread`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/extensions/task-extension) you should use in Unity

Note that your `if` condition should also be a `||` instead of `&&` so

```c#
public void DownloadStarted()
{
    StorageReference asset_ref = storage.GetReferenceFromUrl("gs://dummy_link.appspot.com/test_folder/Test_Asset/testbox");

    asset_ref.GetDownloadUrlAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread((Task<Uri> task) =>
    {
        // I think here it should be || instead of &&
        if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled)
        {
            Debug.Log(task.Exception.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("download link generated");
            Debug.Log("Download URL: " + task.Result);
            downloadLink = task.Result;
            _isDownload = true;

            StartCoroutine(DownloadAsset(task.Result));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `public void DownloadStarted()
    {`
       
 `StorageReference asset_ref = storage.GetReferenceFromUrl(dummy link); `
` asset_ref.GetDownloadUrlAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread((Task<Uri> task) =>
        { ...`

Like this?

Comment: Yeah basically exactly as you had it just replacing `ContinueWith` by `ContinueWithOnMainThread` (and if needed add the namespace etc)

Comment: tested with it, still stuck at the same place.

But thank you for answering my question.

Comment: @GuanShengWong did you check for errors? It should be `if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled)` instead of `&&` maybe your request failed but you tried to access `task.Result`. Check if your URL is correct

Comment: yes, after followed your edited comment.

I managed to get this error.
`System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Firebase.Storage.StorageException: Permission denied. Could not perform this operation  Http Code: 403
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) Firebase.Storage.StorageException: Permission denied. Could not perform this operation  Http Code: 403<---`